# Is there a way to say "false" (adj) such that it cannot mean "lie" (n) or some other meaning?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-requests

Every entry in the dictionary that I have found that has the meaning, "false" or "falsehood," is either a prefix (thus can't stand on its own) or has other meanings.

A lie is an intentionally false statement whereas a false statement can be unintentional. For example, someone very uneducated might say that there is no such thing as outer space and believe it; that is a false statement but not a lie. However, every lie is a false statement, but it must be intentional.

Essentially, the only way that I know how to say, "That statement is false," for example, is some variation of「その発言は嘘です。」which would be calling it a lie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 間違い (noun); 間違った (adjectival); 間違う (verb)
- 誤り (noun); 誤った (adjectival); 誤る (verb)
- 正しくない (adjectival)
- 偽【ぎ】 (noun; used only in the context of logic or programming)

誤る is more formal than 間違う. "That statement is false/incorrect" can be:

- その発言は間違っています。
- その発言は間違いです。
- その発言は誤っています。
- その発言は正しくありません。

Comment: Thank you for an actually useful answer instead of misguided comments. That is increasingly rare on stack exchanges. :)